# System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' from assembly 'System.Web

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I use .NET 6 in my project but it shows me this Error message.

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' from assembly 'System.Web

I tried many solutions, one of which is to update VS2022, but no solution I can find on the internet works.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you please share the realted codes?  How you use the httcontext inside your application?

Comment: I don't use the HttpContext inside my code

Comment: Which line show the error?  Please add some related codes, without codes no one could help you .

Comment: Please share the code producing the error. Also is it a new project or a project migrated from .NET Framework? `System.Web` is namespace which usually is used in older .NET Framework apps. Potentially check the installed nugets - see if they support newer framework.

Comment: app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages(); <--------- here the error message rise
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Agendas}/{action=GetAll}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapFallbackToController("GetAll", "Agendas");
});
app.Run();

Comment: it is a new .net 6 project

Comment: There's no `System.Web` in .NET 6. Somehow you're using a .NET Framework class or NuGet package

Comment: I'm following the .net 6 style I don't use System.Web any where in the application

Comment: Post enough code to reproduce the error *in the question itself*. Include the actual full exception text, including any inner exceptions, stack traces etc. `MapRazorPages` won't cause such an error.

Comment: @Firas .NET 6 isn't a style and that exception didn't come by itself. Post the actual full exception text. Post enough code to reproduce the error. Creating a new Razor Pages project with `dotnet new webapp` *won't* throw such an error. Somehow, you added something that depends on .NET Framework

Comment: What does your `csproj` contain? Any direct references to libraries? Any custom NuGet packages? Right now there's *no* information in the question and what you describe simply can't be reproduced

Comment: Steps to reproduce??

Comment: System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'

Comment: I use some custom nuget packages that are confidential

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already found on the internet `System.Web.HttpContextBase` is not available in **.NET 6**, you can try to search in the whole directory for `system.Web.HttpContextBase` or `HttpContextBase` and delete the dependencies.